# How to form Xpath with irrelevant nodes in between two target nodes

Tags: xpath

How would I obtain a node using Xpath that sometimes has irrelevant nodes in between goal nodes.

I have xml file typically in the form as following:

```
<body>
    <target>
         <goal>Text I want to obtain</goal>
    </target>
    <target2>
         <goal>Second Target I want to obtain</goal>
    </target2>
<body>
```

And I need to throw target's goal and target2's goals in separate string.
So I got the "Text I want to obtain" using Xpath "//body/target/goal", and got the "Second Target I want to obtain" using Xpath "//body/target2/goal".

Very simple.

However later I found out that in between target and goal (or target 2 and goal) there could be separate nodes (not known) as following:

```
<body>
    <target>
         <annoying>
              <goal>Text I want to obtain</goal>
         </annoying>
    </target>
    <target2>
         <noidea>
              <goal>Second Target I want to obtain</goal>
         </noidea>
    </target2>
<body>
```

I still have to distinguish the two targets so I cannot just accumulate goal with "//goal". What kind of 2 Xpaths wold I need to obtain each text I need to obtain?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a wildcard between `target`/`target2` and `goal`:

```
//body/target/*/goal
```

```
//body/target2/*/goal
```

Comment: Ah there you go. I only got those string that has something in between target and goal. However. I could obtain the original result with my original xpath and | it. Making my result Xpath as "//body/target/goal | //body/target/*/goal". Is there shorter way like regular expression? something like "//body/target/[*/]*goal"?