# How to form Xpath with unknown number of irrelevant nodes in between two target nodes

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, xml-parsing

OK so this is the issue I am encountering continuing from the question I have asked earlier.

[How to form Xpath with irrelevant nodes in between two target nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118569/how-to-form-xpath-with-irrelevant-nodes-in-between-two-target-nodes)

Above is the original question.
I was hoping I would be able to get the answer from the person who answered the question but I could not so I will post it separately.

So as I feared, the more irrelevant tag showed up in between my target nodes.  Making me assume that it is possible to have infinite amount of irrelevant tag in between my target tag and the root. I know for sure there is always target/target2 and goal.

```
<body>
    <target>
         <annoying>
             ...
             <x>
                 <goal>Text I want to obtain</goal>
             </x>
             ...
         </annoying>
    </target>
    <target2>
         <noidea>
             ...
             <y>
                 <goal>Second Target I want to obtain</goal>
             </y>
             ...
         </noidea>
    </target2>
<body>
```

I was hoping something like following was possible:

```
//body/target/[*/]*goal
```

Like regular expression to obtain the goal.
However, that exact above Xpath is not a good syntax.

I still have to distinguish target and target2 so

```
//goal
```

would not return me the result I would like.

Is there any Xpath that can obtain goal?

Comment: if you want to be very specific and the goal is going to be always nested at the same lever you can use `/body/target/*/*/goal` or you can use `//` as pointed by other people like this `/body/target//goal` and then your whole subtree will be flattened and all `goal` elements will be selected regardless of how much nested they are.

Answer (score 1):

To get all goals, just use:

```
//goal
```

If you have a target tag, use `//` just when necessary, since performance-wise, that "operator" is much worse than `/`:

```
/body/target//goal
```

Comment: nah for this one i had to distinguish between target and target2. sorry I should have been clearer

Comment: You do can use `//`. But take care as it can be not so performant on XPath evaluators.

Comment: so I am assuming correctly to only use // if you dont know what could go in between the root and the tag you are looking for?

Comment: Yep. `/` means direct descendant and  `//` means "any descendant".

Comment: Actually `//` means `/descendant-or-self::`, so it also includes the current node.

Comment: @JensErat Oh, yeah, Jens, definitely. When I explained, I had that in mind, but, as you pointed out, I see I may have not been so clear about it. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

```
//target//goal
```

and

```
//target2//goal
```

did the trick did not realize I can use // other than beginning

Answer (score 0):

Xpath Axes are what you want

`descendant-or-self::goal` on the a node would select all nodes with a name of goal from teh one you are on and everything nested in it.